# What happened to the 'suspend' and 'shut down' commands?

Tags: 13.10

Just upgraded to 13.10 and my handy 'suspend' and 'shut down' commands are gone!

That is, hitting ALT to reveal the command menu, and typing in 'suspend' or 'shut down' doesn't reveal anything!

Thoughts?

Thanks!

-m

Comment: It is a bug only happens after suspend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for panel indicators thru Hud has been removed, may come back down the road, may not.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/hud/+bug/1165420

Comment: what's HUD? and It seems most other commands through what you called HUD are working just fine! just suspend and shut down are missing...

Comment: Hud is what pops up when you press alt, as far as 'other' commands I don't know, don't use Hud, read bug report

Comment: Got it... interesting discussion! Thanks, @doug!

Comment: HUD=Heads Up Display for when we are flying our Ubuntu jets!